# Scaling dynos... ! ▸ Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: python, heroku

I have problem with deploying telegram bot on heroku. But I have problem like this:

```
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

I also tried:

```
heroku run 'grep worker Procfile'
Running grep worker Procfile on ⬢ sleepy-coast-07985... up, run.6768 (Free)
grep: Procfile: No such file or directory
```

`